# First principle proof for derivatives of $\arcsin{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

One popular proof is to take $\sin{y} = x$ and then differentiate on both sides. But how do you prove it from first principles? Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't that proof from first principles? It's a general principle that if you know the derivative of a function, and it has an inverse, then you know the derivative of the inverse, just by the chain rule.

Answer (score 6):

Is this cheating? We want the limit as $h$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\arcsin h-0}{h}$. Let $w=\arcsin h$. So we are interested in the limit of $\frac{w}{\sin w}$ as $w$ approaches $0$.  Upside down, but familiar!

Now we know the derivative at $0$. We can get the derivative at $x$ by using the $\arcsin$ version of the addition law for sines.

Comment: +1) No that is not cheating, sine must come into play somehow.

Comment: @AD.: One can *imagine* defining $\arcsin$ first, for example as an integral. Just like with exponential/logarithm, we can take one or the other as fundamental.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Personally, I like to define $\arcsin$ as the inverse of $\sin$ around 0.

Comment: It's not cheating, but it only gives the derivative at $x=0$...